# Charles Proxy Windows 10 https: SSLHandshake: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: c#, ssl, proxy, windows-10

I am trying to see the https queries that are being fired by my windows 10 application.

I have installed the Charles SSL certificate (under help-> SSL proxy -> install Charles Root certificate)

And under SSL Proxing settings I have checked Enabe SS proxing and have also added my location :  api.mywebsite.com

however when i am looking at Charles i see:
URL https://api.mywebsite.com
Status  Failed
Failure SSLHandshake: Remote host closed connection during handshake
Notes   You may need to configure your browser or application to trust the Charles Root Certificate. See SSL Proxying in the Help menu.

but its not working has anyone have this issue?

Comment: You certainly need to import the certificate in your client too. Not sure how this is done in windows 10 though.

Comment: Going to the url  http://www.charlesproxy.com/getssl should give me an ssl certificate to download, however it does nothing for me on my Windows Phone 10